# Xamarin : SyncFusion SFPdfViewer 16.1.0.32 crashing after changing the compiler to Android 10 with Xamarin Forms 2.5.1.444934

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

My Xamarin project has recently changed the compiler to android 10 due to Google store policy. We use Xamarin Forms 2.5.1.444934. I have been using SyncFusions SfPdfViewer
(16.1.0.32) to date for PDF viewing purposes in the application. However, whenever i open a pdf, the app crashes with a stacktrace of :

Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Drawable com.myproj_test.mobile:animator/design_appbar_state_list_animator with resource ID #0x7f020000'

Can someone please provide me with some info/insight regarding this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We have created a replication sample based on the information provided, but it is working as expected. Kindly share the following details to analyze more on this issue and assist you with the better solution

1. Simple sample/ modify the above sample to reproduce the issue.
2. PDF document.
3. Replication video/ procedure to reproduce the issue.

Please find the sample in the below link, which we have used to reproduce the issue in our end
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GettingStarted-1723071657.zip

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Ashok Kumar Viswanathan.